# Determine when the iOS device was last off and for how long?

Tags: ios

Can anyone think of a way to determine when the iOS device was last powered off and for how long?

Comment: Is this for an app store app, or can it use private APIs?  Or is it even for jailbroken devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer there's no way to detect when the device is powering off or powering on.  I also can't find anything in Apple's docs about it.
[power on events in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473827/power-on-events-in-iphone)

I'm not familiar with jail broken devices though.  It'd be a good feature.