# Record each time a jailbroken iDevice power On/Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to record the time when an iDevice turns On/Off and then save it in a database when the device turns on.I will save both the turn-off and turn-on time when the iDevice turns-on.

I tried to do this in android using the broadcastreceiver, is this possible in iOS?

I found a list of public notifications in https://gist.github.com/hpique/7554209 and its not there.

I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [power on events in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473827/power-on-events-in-iphone)

Comment: @Paulw11, that question should not be considered a duplicate.  This question specifically mentions a jailbroken phone (which the other does not), which opens up techniques not normally available.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24692133/119114).  This question should also **not** be considered a duplicate, because jailbreaking is not the same thing as simply being open to Private API usage.  However, the answer I link to does assume jailbreaking (since it uses a daemon).  It gives you the power on time, and *kind of* gives you the power off time, as long as your daemon polls the system uptime regularly.

Comment: @Nate the link you gave me was helpful.. Thank you.

Comment: That's a list of *public* notifications. Try subscribing to all notifications and printing them while turning your device on and off, and see what you get.