# iOS shutdown Notification

Tags: ios, notifications, shutdown

Is there a way to get notified (by iOS) that the system is about to shutdown?
I'm particularly interested in when the battery is dead and the OS is about to shutdown as a result.

I thought `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` will do the trick but it doesn't.

Thanks.

The app is running in the foreground.
I basically just need to log the timestamp (of when the battery dies) and save to a file just before the device shutdown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [power on events in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473827/power-on-events-in-iphone)

Comment: not possible next best thing it to implement - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application method in your appDelegate

Comment: Thanks @ShamsAhmed, the `(void)applicationWillTerminate` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First, the answer unfortunately is **NO**.

Still you'd had to differentiate two cases:

1. Your app is in **foreground**: In this case, you can at least get the battery level using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]`. Check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel).
2. Your app is in **background**: If your app is in the background, it will just get sent a *KILL* signal (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473827/power-on-events-in-iphone)), which is not the same as a notification that you can subscribe or listen to.

You could try and go for checking the battery level in the background, but this probably won't fit your case either. Background execution is only allowed in [very specific cases](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) on iOS, among them *location updates*, *VOIP*, *UIBackgroundTask*... none of which seems to be appropriate for you on first sight... :/

[Here](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) is an excellent read on multitasking on iOS, maybe you find something that suits your case...

Answer (score 0):

not possible next best thing it to implement 
`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` 
method in your **appDelegate** by  *Shams Ahmed*